# users forced to reset password

Tags: 7, users

I'm on 7.39 and I get a lot of reports from users that re forced to reset their password every time they visit the site.

I'm honestly clueless about how to debug and haven't been able to find similar support requests on the forums.

Any ideas are extremely welcome

**update**
Here's feedback from a user that couldn't even reset:

*If I use this link: http://www.tambourhinoceros.net/user/user-id/orders/order-id:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

If I try to login ... with this e-mail adress and my password ... nothing happens.
If I request a new passwort this message
appears

> There was a problem with your form submission. Please wait 6 seconds
>   and try again. You must be a human, not a spam bot, to submit forms on
>   this website. If you insist that you are a human, please try again. If
>   error persists, contact webmaster using contact link at the bottom of
>   this page and give all the details of this error (your browser,
>   version, OS). Form is submitted too fast. Please spend more time
>   filling in the form.

*

Comment: perhaps someone installed a password reset module?

Comment: @NoSssweat nope - and it's not all users. Just a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was caused by a conflict between botcha and honeybot. Disabling botcha fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Password Policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy) module to manage your password policies.

Comment: That won't solve whatever configuration problem is currently causing users to have to reset their passwords though.

Comment: Hi rooby - I am not sure it will or will not - depends on the problem, but it gives @kristoffer-rom somewhere to start.  The effort involved in installing the module is much less than hunting down the problem, and worst cast the problem is not solved.  So the effort / benefit might makes it worth it.

Comment: Generally it isn't a good idea to leave a bug and work around it instead of fixing the underlying problem.

Comment: lol.  Yes I agree 100%.  Kristof mentioned he does not know where to start.  My suggestion was aimed at giving him a starting point for finding the problem, and there is a remote chance (without too much investment required time-was) that this would actually solve the bug.  But at least there is somewhere to start.